# Не получается посмотреть содержимое объектного файла

Tags: c++

Хотел посмотреть содержимое объектного файла. Полгода назад смотрел всё хорошо работало.

Ввожу:

```
g++ main.cpp
objdump -x a.out
```

Сейчас выводит такую ошибку:

```
a.out:  file format mach-o 64-bit x86-64
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/objdump: error: 'a.out': Invalid/Unsupported object file format
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код программы? Версия компилятора? Какая ОС?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Код программы: просто одна функция main. Компилятор Xcode Version 13.2.1 (13C100). Os X.